# Having Issues Making A Navigation Bar in Header

Tags: html, css, header, navigation

I am trying to make a Navigation Bar for the top of my page

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2C2F33;
  border-bottom: 2.5px #FF9F00 solid;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#logo img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 187.5px;
  height: 63.75px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar,
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 22.5px 0 22.5px;
}

.navbar,
li,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar,
li,
a:hover {
  color: #FF9F00;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#dollarydoos,
#dsh {
  color: #FF9F00;
}

#dosh {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div id="logo">

    <img src="./img/logo.png"></img>

  </div>

  <div class="navbar">

    <div id="leftnavbar">

      <ul>

        <li><span id="dollarydoos">Dollarydoos:</span> <span id="dosh">1.00000000</span> <span id="dsh">DSH</span></li>

      </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="rightnavbar">

      <ul>

        <li><a href="index.html">Button1</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.html">Button2</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.html">Button3</a></li>

        <li><a href="index.html">Button4</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I cant get the buttons and the dollardoos to have a small box that surrounds it (inside) and to align to the center of the logo and get listed in line in the center.

Like this:

[image]

How can I do this as I am not too experienced in HTML/CSS. I am a newbie trying to build his own site.

Comment: those the dollarydoos is generated from php !?

Comment: @M0ns1f no php. I dont even know php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a flexbox of the `header` and removed `display:inline` for the `navbar`

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2C2F33;
  border-bottom: 2.5px #FF9F00 solid;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 187.5px;
  height: 63.75px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: auto;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 22.5px 0 22.5px;
}

.navbar,
li,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar,
li,
a:hover {
  color: #FF9F00;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#dollarydoos,
#dsh {
  color: #FF9F00;
}

#dosh {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div id="leftnavbar">
      <ul>
        <li><span id="dollarydoos">Dollarydoos:</span> <span id="dosh">1.00000000</span> <span id="dsh">DSH</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rightnavbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Button1</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Button2</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Button3</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Button4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you push the elements to the right side?

Also what does flexbox exactly do? I tried learning it but never grasped it

Comment: Pushed to the right now using margin-left:auto for navbar. Flexbox is used to make the creation of layouts easier. For a good explanation see here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: What does margin-left: auto do in this case then?

Comment: It takes as much margin as it can get, pushing the element to the right.

Comment: So if it was margin-right: auto it would push it left, right? And if yes; if margin-top --> to the bottom and so forth right?

Comment: I am trying to add background to the whole thing and this is my current css:

https://pastebin.com/m8uc42XE

Can you help me fix those annoying wrong colors in the header @Gerard